# Programmatically build string for printf

Tags: bash

I’m trying to build up a colourful line to be printed to my terminal.

I’m writing my message to a file with Ruby.

```
def warn(line)
  log = File.open("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../log/import/import.log", "a")
  log.puts("WARN #{line}")
  log.close
end
```

A typical line written to the log file will look like this:

```
WARN Client insertion failed: [149] Validation failed: Email is invalid
```

I’m continuously reading from this file with `tail`:

```
tail -F -n 0 log/import/import.log | script/report.sh
```

The script I’m piping the `tail` output to looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

while read LINE; do
  case "$LINE" in
    "file truncated")
      clear
      ;;
    INFO*)
      tput setaf 6
      echo "${LINE:5}"
      tput sgr0
      ;;
    WARN*)
      tput setaf 1
      printf "${LINE:5}" | cut -d ":" -f1
      tput sgr0
      printf ": "
      tput setaf 3
      printf "["
      tput sgr0
      printf "${LINE:5}" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1
      tput setaf 3
      printf "]"
      tput sgr0
      printf "${LINE:5}" | cut -d "]" -f2
      printf "\n"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "$LINE"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

My output is being printed onto separate lines, so it looks like this:

[image: Current terminal output]

However, I’d like each error to be printed on its own line, like this:

[image: desired output]

How can I make this work?

---

After receiving some excellent answers, I refactored my script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

printfg() {
  tput setaf $3
  printf "$1" "$2"
  tput sgr0
}

while read LINE; do
  case "$LINE" in
    "file truncated")
      clear
      ;;
    INFO*)
      printfg "%s\n" "${LINE:5}" 6
      ;;
    WARN*)
      IFS="[]" read error number reason <<< "$(echo "${LINE:5}")"
      printfg "%s" "$error" 1
      printfg "%s" "[" 3
      printf "%s" "$number"
      printfg "%s" "]" 3
      printf "%s\n" "$reason"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "$LINE"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `printf "$var"`. Use `printf '%s' "$var"` instead. This will save you lots of headaches if one day `$var` contains a percent sign or starts with a hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `cut` command outputs a newline `\n` character at the end of the output.

One way to overcome this is to use some command substitution technique

for example

```
$printf "hello world" | cut -f1
hello world
$
```

can be modified as

```
output=`printf "hello world" | cut -f1`
printf $output
hello world$
```

see the bash prompt `$` at the end of output `hello world`

Answer (score 1):

The final call to `cut` in this line

```
printf "${LINE:5}" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1
```

produces a newline, since it outputs full lines. Instead, use

```
code=${LINE:5}; code=${code%*}; printf "$code";
```

Comment: It is more safe to write `printf "%s" "$code"`. Finally you could write `code=${LINE:5}; printf "%s" "${code%*}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `cut` by using `read` and setting `IFS` in this way:

```
LINE="WARN Client insertion failed: [149] Validation failed: Email is invalid"

case "$LINE" in
  WARN*)
    IFS="[]" read error number reason <<< "$(echo "${LINE:5}")"
    # echo "$error | $number | $reason"
    tput setaf 1
    printf "%s" "$error"
    tput sgr0
    # printf ": "
    tput setaf 3
    printf "["
    tput sgr0
    printf "%s" "$number"
    tput setaf 3
    printf "]"
    tput sgr0
    printf "%s" "$reason"
    printf "\n"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: That’s brilliant. Thanks for that. I’ll updated my question with how I eventually refactored for future readers.

Comment: I’m getting so much mileage out of this trick. Someone set up a SaaS that lets me send beers to people.